# comparison between two arrays

Tags: arrays, java-8

The first input request i got from client-side is (A1): [1, 3, 7, 9, 12]. I am trying to update this array. Array is now something like this (A2): [5, 7, 8, 12]. Here A2 has some elements which are new/old as compare with A1.

I want to create to 3 arrays which separates all this elements. Elements which are common, elements in array A2 which are new and elements which are removed when compared with A1. Something like this:

```
FA1=[1, 3, 9]
FA2=[5, 8]
FA3=[7, 12]
```

I tried this:

```
    List<String> arr = Arrays.asList("1", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "12");

    List<String> aru = Arrays.asList("1","2", "5", "7", "10", "12");

    List<String> removed = new ArrayList<String>();

    List<String> added = new ArrayList<String>();

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.size(); i++) {
        if (!aru.contains(arr.get(i))) {
            removed.add(arr.get(i));
        } 
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < aru.size(); i++) {
        if (!arr.contains(aru.get(i))) {
            added.add(aru.get(i));
        }
    }
```

removed element array i found is: [3, 4, 6, 8] and 
 new array/added element in array as [2, 10]

How to optimize this solution?

Comment: 1. Do not deal with `String` instead of `Integer` 2. You could have chosen `Set` as your collecting data type for `arr` and `aru`, if the current use case is the only interaction they are responsible for. 3. What kind of optimisation other than that are you looking for?

Comment: look into `retainAll` and `removeAll` e.g. `List<String> common = new ArrayList<>(arr);  common.retainAll(aru);` etc...

Comment: At I got this array [4, 5, 8], then i applied some manipulation on those elements like adding permissions. Later i thought to update this array, now array is [1, 2, 4, 5]. In here 1 & 2 are new element in updated array, but 8 is removed and 4,5 are still their. So for removed elements i will call different manipulations and new added element different. For this reason i want to do this. Solution i got you've seen. Is this proper solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To simplify the code, you can use already available `List` methods for your purpose:

```
List<String> input = Arrays.asList("1", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "12");
List<String> updated = Arrays.asList("1","2", "5", "7", "10", "12");

List<String> commonElements = new ArrayList<>(input);
commonElements.retainAll(updated);
// now commonElements contains: [1, 5, 7, 12]

List<String> removedElements = new ArrayList<>(input);
removedElements.removeAll(updated);
// now removedElements contains: [3, 4, 6, 8]

List<String> addedElements = new ArrayList<>(updated);
addedElements.removeAll(input);
// now addedElements contains: [2, 10]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve by using some of Java's internal methods as below.

```
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        list.add(1);
        list.add(3);
        list.add(7);
        list.add(9);
        list.add(12);

        List<Integer> list2 = new ArrayList<Integer>(list);
        List<Integer> list1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        list1.add(5);
        list1.add(7);
        list1.add(8);
        list1.add(12);


        list.retainAll(list1);
        list1.removeAll(list);
        list2.removeAll(list);

        System.out.println(list2);
        System.out.println(list1);
        System.out.println(list);
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
    List<String> arr = Arrays.asList("1", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "12");
    List<String> aru = Arrays.asList("1", "2", "5", "7", "10", "12");
    List<String> removed = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> added = new ArrayList<String>();

    if (arr.size() > aru.size()) {

        for (int i = 0; i < arr.size(); i++) {
            if (!aru.contains(arr.get(i))) {
                removed.add(arr.get(i));
            }

            if (aru.size()>i &&  !arr.contains(aru.get(i))) {
                added.add(aru.get(i));
            }
        }

    } else {

        for (int i = 0; i < aru.size(); i++) {
            if (!arr.contains(aru.get(i))) {
                removed.add(aru.get(i));
            }

            if (arr.size()>i && !aru.contains(arr.get(i))) {
                added.add(arr.get(i));
            }
        }

    }
```